# javascript includes method checks same string but gets different results

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a text match in a document using Javascript's `includes()` method. I checked my console to see why no match was returned, and noticed that checking the exact same string for a match returned different results. I'm not sure why this is happening - through some trial and error, I found the offending string to be `the`. For example, when I replaced the `the` in the argument with the `the` from the longer string, it returned true. Does anyone know why this happens?

[image]

```
'Whether you call it the restroom, toilet, loo, WC, lavatory, throne, ladies room, commode, lav or bathroom, few phrases are as essential as knowing how to ask where the bathroom facilities are when you’re travelling!'.includes('Whether you call it the')
false
'Whether you call it the restroom, toilet, loo, WC, lavatory, throne, ladies room, commode, lav or bathroom, few phrases are as essential as knowing how to ask where the bathroom facilities are when you’re travelling!'.includes('Whether you call it the')
true
```

EDIT:
I am getting the description text under a clicked link on the Google search results page, and looking for a match on the new page. I store the description text in chrome local storage and then loop through paragraphs in new page to check for a match

```
chrome.storage.local.get("keyName",function(items) {//initialize the application
            console.log(items.keyName)//'Whether you call it the'
            var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
            for (n=0;n<p.length;n++){
                console.log(p[n].textContent)//'Whether you call it the restroom, toilet, loo, WC, lavatory, throne, ladies room, commode, lav or bathroom, few phrases are as essential as knowing how to ask where the bathroom facilities are when you’re travelling!'
                if (p[n].textContent.includes(items.keyName)){
                    console.log('found a match at paragraph' + p[n])
                    var newStr = p[n].textContent.replace(items.keyName,"<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + items.keyName + "</span>")
                    p[n].innerHTML=newStr
                    $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('p:eq('+n+')').offset().top + 'px'
                    }, 'fast')          
                    return
                }
                else{console.log('no match found')}
            }

})
```

Comment: I get `true` in both cases.

Comment: Take a look at both strings in a hex editor (`echo -n '<MY STRING>' | hexdump -C` on Unix). The first string probably has zero width character somewhere.

Comment: your are right, I mistakenly confused. how ever, I still believe that you have some unwanted char somewhere in the string

Comment: Post the context where you call `includes` twice!

Comment: `p` elements don't preserve spaces and new lines etc. Thus the text may look like it matches but it's not. Try using `pre` to see if it works! (`pre` are not the solution but just to see if it works or not)!

Comment: unfortunately, i can only search for elements with text that matches the description which are contained in `p` elements. Also, the two strings converted to hex are also the same